# Java using this keyword inside a thread created inside a class

Tags: java, this

I have some code like this:

```
class MyClass{
    final ArrayList<Thread> list= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        new Thread(()->{
            //more instructions...
            list.remove(this);
        }).start();
}
```

The question is about a warning shown by IntelliJ for the instruction `list.remove(list);` telling me: `ArrayList<Thread> may not contains objects of type MyClass`

Is it a wrong analysis by IntelliJ, or `this` keyword in my scenario is referencing the enclosing class `MyClass`?

Comment: Your lambda function is not a member of `Thread`; it's just getting passed into the Thread constructor. So `this` cannot be your Thread object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Runnable to avoid `this` keyword conflict.

Answer (score 6):

`this` refers to the `MyClass` instance.

That is because you are using a lambda expression, which possesses no `this` context on its own.

But even if you replaced the lambda expression with an anonymous subclass, like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        list.remove (this);
    }
})
```

Then `this` would refer to the anonymous subclass of `Runnable`, and not to a `Thread` instance.

Answer (score 1):

this keyword is reffering to the object which calls the method. In this case MyClass. Your list contains threads. Your code is trying to remove this object(myclass) from a list containing threads.

Which doesnt make sense

Comment: Yes I understand the sense of the warning, the thing is why is MyClass is refernced instead of Thread, but based on @MC Emperor's response this is because of using lambda expression

Comment: its not because of lambda, its because you are defining the method in that class(myclass). Every time you use "this" inside a class blueprint it will refer to the instance which calls the method. MC EMP is pointing out that the lamba expression DOESNT change what "this" is reffering to.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Runnable` instead will help you avoid wrapped contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround that fits my need:

```
class MyClass{
final ArrayList<Runnable> list= new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //more instructions...
        list.remove(this);
    }
}).start();
```

I changed the list so it contains `Runnable` objects, then `this` will refer to Runnable class.